# About matrix of edge in graph using c++

Tags: c++, graph, graph-theory

I confuse how to define the program that will find the matrix of edge in a graph.
The problem is if one inputs the value of adjacency matrix that give information about connection of vertices in a graph, example : there are 3 vertices, then V1 connected to V2 but not with V3, then V2 connected to V3, it gives :

0    1    0
1    0    1
0    1    0

now, with that information, I want to make the program which find the connection of edge to edge, example there are 3 edges : 1-2 edge, 2-3 edge, and its output is :

0     1
1     0

I know to make the first output "Adjacency matrix", but the second. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. "then V1 connected to V2 but not with V3" - shouldn't the first row of the matrix be "0 1 0" then instead of "0 1 1"?

Comment: 2. Do you mean that edges are connected if they share a vertex? It may help if you make another example where the number of vertices is not equal to the number of edges.

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An adjacency matrix is used to represent a graph which means you have both vertices and edges in it. So if the input is :

0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0

It means your graph is complete. If you read it with putting numbers on your matrix:

X 1 2 3
1  0 1 1
2  1 0 1
3  1 1 0

You can see that:

V1 connects to V2 and V3
V2 connects to V1 and V3
V3 connects to V1 and V2

By reading row n you see which vertice Vn connects to and by reading column n you can see which vertices are connected to Vn.

In your example, your graph is non-oriented because your matrix is diagonal.

If your aim is to find what are the edges of your graph, you already have the information in the adjacency matrix. If you want to see what vertices are "double connected" you need to find if for vertices Vi and Vj the M[i][j] and the M[j][i] members of your matrix both have the value 1 (It is always the case in non-oriented graph). A possible algorithm for that is just a double loop on your matrix representation (generally two vectors/lists/arrays).