# Why my algorithm for calculating adjacency matrix outputs '8' when only 0 and 1 should be used?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a graph program right now, but it isn't finished yet, it's about my question before  ([About matrix of edge in graph using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593223/about-matrix-of-edge-in-graph-using-c/22593974?noredirect=1#22593974)), and this is some sample program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n, m = 0, i, j, k, l;
   cout << "How many vertex in graph : ";
   cin >> n;
   cout << endl << endl;

   int A[n][n], A1[n][n];

   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
      {
         cout << "A[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
         cin >> A[i][j];
         if (A[i][j] == 1)
            m++;
      }

   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
         A1[i][j] = A[i][j];

   m = m / 2;
   int B[m][m];
   cout << endl << "Adjacency Matrix A : " << endl;
   /* Problem
   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
      {
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        if(j == n)
            cout << endl;
      }
   */
   cout << endl;

   /* Problem's maker
   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
      for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        if(A1[i][j] == 1)
        {
            for(k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                for(l = 1; l <= n; l++)
                    if(A1[k][l] == 1)
                    {
                        if(k == i && l == j)
                            B[i][j] == 0;
                        else if (k == j  && l == i)
                            A1[k][l] == 0;
                        else if(k == i || k == j || l == i || l == j)
                            B[i][j] == 1;
                        else
                            B[i][j] == 0;
                    }
        }*/
```

and, if I input sequentially 0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0. I absolutely sure the output is :

0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 0

but it gives :

0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 8

This part where I have no idea, I think it's cause by `/*Problem maker`. I know I don't understand C++ well enough, but for `/*Problem` part I'm sure I get it right. Even though `/*Problem maker` part is wrong by its algorithms or whatever, it doesn't connected with the `/*Problem` part right?

If I deleted the `/*Problem maker` part, the output is well and nice.

Comment: What is *peculiar* in this error ?

Comment: What is the point of this line `A1[i][j] = A[i][j];`

Comment: You're invoking a UB, accessing matrix outside range 0 to n-1

Comment: BTW- Computers start counting at zero

Comment: @Ed Heal, the part is to copy all of A value to A1, I think we can ignore that part,

Comment: haccks, I don't know if I put the right word "peculiar" cause english is not my first language, but I believe you can see in my question about 8 value changing to 0, if I deleted the *Problem maker part.

Comment: Btw. please try to construct the title of your question in a way that actually describes the problem. I've tried to come up with something and changed the title, but really, you should do it yourself next time. "help me with error" or "geesh, what happens here" or "the most interesting problem" does really not help in finding that question later. After three months, you'll get involved in another most interesting (or peculiar) problem, and it's actually not that interesting or peculiar. On the other hand, mentioning adjacency matrix and output/formatting errors or data corruption helps much!

Comment: P0W, can you explain more thoroughly, please.

Comment: @user3452508 - the for loops

Comment: this should not even complie... `int A[n][n], A1[n][n];`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, sorry I will do it in my next question.

Comment: @Ryzhehvost why not ?

Comment: @P0W array dimensions has to be constant expressions

Comment: @Ed Heal, where is the part of zero counting.

Comment: @Ryzhehvost , no it's not, The truth is dimention of array must be defined before the declaration of its dimention itself in array.
n = 3;
then
A[n][n];

Comment: @yagamilight1994 vs2010 shows `error C2057: expected constant expression` I trust him more than you.

Comment: @Ryzhehvost since `C++11` you can, and on some implementation too like MingW 4.8.1

Comment: BTW, this 
`if(k == i && l == j)  B[i][j] == 0; else if (k == j  && l == i)      A1[k][l] == 0; else if(k == i || k == j || l == i || l == j)      B[i][j] == 1; else      B[i][j] == 0;`
will do nothing.

Comment: @Ryzhehvost, I'm very begining on this, so I still get wrong on many idea or program, but thanks, I still working on this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `int A[n][n] ;`

`A` can only be traversed for all rows starting from  `i = 0 to n-1` on all columns starting from `j = 0 to n-1`

Accessing `A[n][n]` invokes a undefined behavior

Of course you can fix this by *different* approachs

Comment: By the way, it works, but I wonder why it happened, if I think the problem is just about dimention there is no different between 0 to n-1 and 1 - n.

Comment: I think with A[1][1] to A[n][n] has value 0, or 1, and ignore A[0][0] it's not problem, because I print only 1 to n, but the problem is fixed by @P0W but, the "reason" itself is not fixed. Maybe you can explain more?

Comment: when you try to access a[n][n] you will get to the unallocated memory area. Results are undefined - it can be a sefalut, or wrong results(like you get), or even correct working (from time to time). In your case looks like this memory changes after you write to it, that's why you got 8 instead of 1 or 0. Your allocated array ends at a[n-1][n-1].

Comment: @yagamilight1994 Don't you see in your loop ? Answer yourself what happens when `i` equals  `n` or `j` equals `n` or when both equals `n`'. All are UB - `A[n][j]`, `A[i][n]`, `A[n][n]`

Comment: @Ryzhehvost and P0W, maybe with your help I get a new Idea of programming, so if I declare A[n][n], it allocates memory on A[0][0] to A[n-1][n-1]? not A[n][n]?